# How to Continue to Change Element with While Loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I've been trying to get display a bunch of letters that continuously change. They only change each time I reload the page. Please help.

```js
    const action = false;
    var i = 0; 
    
    function randomized() {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      const still = document.getElementById('c1');
      const still2 = [document.getElementById('c1'),document.getElementById('c2'),document.getElementById('c3'),document.getElementById('c4'),document.getElementById('c5'),document.getElementById('c6'),document.getElementById('c7'),document.getElementById('c8'),document.getElementById('c9'),document.getElementById('c10'),document.getElementById('c11'),document.getElementById('c12')]
    
    while (action === false) {
     i++;
     var letter = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
     still2[i].innerHTML = letter;
    }
      /*for(var i = 0; action === false; i++){
       var letter = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
        still2[i].innerHTML = letter;
     };*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer the `while` loop will lock the main thread and it will never render anything. I suggest using the [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function to queue the updates for the elements.

Below is a proof of concept you can adapt to your specific case:

- A function to generate the random character
- User global `<span>` selector for simplicity
- A function to loop through the elements, update their content and queue the next frame indefinitely.
- For the demo purposes stop the loop after 2 seconds. Note how the last frame animation is logged and used to then stop the infinite loop.

```js
// Generate random letter
function randomLetter() {
  const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}

// Id to stop the animation frame loop
let animationId = 0;

// Update all nodes at the same time
function updateNodes() {
  // List all nodes to update
  let nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].innerHTML = randomLetter();
  }

  // Queue the next update
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(updateNodes);
}

// Start the animation loop
animationId = requestAnimationFrame(updateNodes);

// Stops animation after 2 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Comment: @stealththeninja thank you for the updates. The `nodes` variable was defined outside of the function so the DOM query is not executed on every iteration.

Comment: Good point: more efficient to make the node collection once. Made the edit trying to remove it from global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Call your page load method inside `window.onload` and use `localStorage`

```
 window.onload = function() { 
        randomized(localStorage.getItem("randomString"));// Retrieve
 }

function randomized(preRandomString){
    // Store and update localStorage
    return prvRandomString + localStorage.setItem("randomString", "abc123");
}
```

Comment: the letters only load once. looking to have them continually change.

Comment: Use `localStroage` to save the previous random string. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop locks the thread and prevents the page from rendering each of your letters. Try [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or similar asynchronous loop to release the thread and show each new letter:

```js
function setRandomLetter() {
  const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  const still = document.getElementById('c1');
  const letter = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  still.innerText = letter;
}

// set a random letter every second
setInterval(setRandomLetter, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="c1"></span>
```